# Strings manipulation in java

Tags: java

I have a multiline String as below,I want to lift  'VC-38NN' whenever String line contains 'Profoma invoice'. My code below still prints everything once the search string is found.

```
Payment date
receipt serial
Profoma invoice VC-38NN
Welcome again
```

```
if(multilineString.toLowerCase().contains("Profoma invoice".toLowerCase()))
{
    System.out.println(multilineString+"");
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("Profoma invoice not found");
}
```

Comment: I don't see multiline String. I see one line String.

Comment: The code prints the unmodified multilineString plus an empty String. that's printing "everything"

Comment: Look into regular expressions (capturing groups in particular).

Comment: @meriton Split with `\n` then traverse with `for` may be better :-)

Comment: "My code below still prints everything once the search string is found." - if you mean that your code executes the 'if-condition' instead of the 'else condition', then that's exactly what you told it to do. You need to work on your question to explain to us what you don't understand about what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible solutions:

```
String input = "Payment date\n" +
        "receipt serial\n" +
        "Profoma invoice VC-38NN\n" +
        "Welcome again";

// non-regex solution
String uppercased = input.toUpperCase();
// find "profoma invoice"
int profomaInvoiceIndex = uppercased.indexOf("PROFOMA INVOICE ");
if (profomaInvoiceIndex != -1) {
    // find the first new line character after "profoma invoice".
    int newLineIndex = uppercased.indexOf("\n", profomaInvoiceIndex);
    if (newLineIndex == -1) { // if there is no new line after that, use the end of the string
        newLineIndex = uppercased.length();
    }
    int profomaInvoiceLength = "profoma invoice ".length();
    // substring from just after "profoma invoice" to the new line
    String result = uppercased.substring(profomaInvoiceIndex + profomaInvoiceLength, newLineIndex);
    System.out.println(result);
}

// regex solution
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^profoma invoice (.+)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation in comments:

```
public class StackOverflow55313851 {

    public final static String TEXT = "Profoma invoice";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String multilineString = "Payment date\n" + 
                   "receipt serial\n" + 
                   "Profoma invoice VC-38NN\n" + 
                   "Welcome again";

        // split text by line breaks
        String[] lines = multilineString.split("\n");
        // iterate over every line
        for (String line : lines) {
            // if it contains desired text
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains(TEXT.toLowerCase())) {
                // find position of desired text in this line
                int indexOfInvoiceText = line.toLowerCase().indexOf(TEXT.toLowerCase());
                // get only part of the line following the desired text
                String invoiceNumber = line.substring(indexOfInvoiceText + TEXT.length() + 1);
                System.out.println(invoiceNumber);
            }
        }
    }

}
```